# Crashlytics Android: app could not be located

Tags: java, android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

To create an application and has built *fabric.io*.

*My app release 1.1* - everything works, statistics comes.

*My app released 1.2* - it does not work, the statistics do not come.

When you come on the dashboard *fabric.io*:

> Alert! Sorry, the app could not be located.

[image]

**An important point:**

If you build debug version - it works!

If the release version of the GoogleStore - is not working! (Although version 1.1 of the GoogleStore - works!)

**Checked logcat release version:**

> Logcat: I/Fabric: Initializing Crashlytics 2.2.2.37

What could be wrong? How to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Proguard for release version?

Comment: @MoralesBatovski Yes!

Comment: Have you added this configuration to you project? https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html or https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html, try adding -keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.** in ProGuard file

Comment: @MoralesBatovski big thanks! It works!

Comment: Nice! I will post like answer and you can accept it ok?

Comment: @MoralesBatovski sure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are building a release version and using ProGuard you should add following lines in your ProGuard file:

```
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

This documentation could be useful for you too [Dex and ProGuard](http://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html) and [Advanced Setup](http://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html).